# Configure Next.js with ESM

Tags: next.js

I have added "type": "module" in my package.json file. And this has led to several issues.

I needed to change jest.config, next.config, tailwind.config, postcss.config into cjs format, as all of them use module.exports.

Also, as I added "type": "module", I deleted the package-lock.json file, node_modules and .next folder and ran npm install.

I have node v14.17.4, and next v11.1.2. Actually starting from next 11 esm should be supported.

I keep getting the error: Error: **Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/Katharina.Schreiber/Desktop/not-just-another-weather-app/.next/server/pages/_document.js
require() of ES modules is not supported**

I assume, it makes no sense to rename files in .next folder. I tried to clear next cache - nothing.

Comment: What were you trying to achieve by adding `"type": "module"` to your Next.js app's `package.json`?

Comment: I have node code and wish to use imports instead require all over my app